# Planning to purchase a new computer with Ubuntu-supported hardwares

Tags: hardware, cpu

I'm planning to purchase a new computer with the most-recent hardware and I just want to make sure that Ubuntu and the Linux kernel support the hardware to buy. One point is that I want to build my own computer, instead of buying some computer from big companies because I don't want a Windows copy :)

The central point is whether intel i7 2600 (sandybridge) is supported by the latest ubuntu and linux version. Also, is there any motherboard that linux cannot understand?

Thanks

Comment: A good rule of thumb is Intel chip-sets are always well supported due to them having open source drivers at least for there video chips.

Answer (score 3):

try to see here:

http://linuxhardware.net/linuxhardware/notes/

http://hardware4linux.info/

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/